# equivalent of nevow.tags.raw for twisted.web.template

Tags: twisted, twisted.web

I'm trying to port [pydoctor](https://launchpad.net/pydoctor) to twisted.web.template and have hit a pretty basic problem: pydoctor uses epydoc to render docstrings into HTML but I can't see a way to include this HTML in the generated page without escaping.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, somewhat intentionally, no way to insert HTML into the page without parsing; `twisted.web.template` is a bit more of a stickler about producing correct output than nevow was.

There are a couple of ways around this.

1. Ultimately, your HTML is going to some kind of output stream.  You could simply insert a renderer that returns a pair of `Deferred` objects, and  does a `.write` to the underlying stream after the first one fires but before the second.  Kind of gross, but it effectively expresses your intent :).
2. You can simply re-parse the output of epydoc into HTML using `XMLString` or similar, so that `twisted.web.template` can write it out correctly.  This will "waste" a little bit of CPU, but in my opinion it will be worth it for (A) the stress-test it will give t.w.t and (B) the guarantee - presuming that `t.w.t` is correct - that it will give you that you're emitting valid HTML.

As I was writing this answer, however, I realized that point 2 isn't generally possible with arbitrary HTML with the current public API of twisted.web.template.  Ideally, you could use `html5lib` to parse this stuff, and then just dump the parsed input into your document tree.

If you don't mind mucking around with private API, you could probably hook up [html5lib's SAX support](https://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation#SAX_Events) to the [internal SAX parser](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/api/twisted.web.template._ToStan.html) that we use to load templates.

Of course, the real solution is to [fix the ticket you already filed](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6519), so you don't have to use private API outside of Twisted itself...

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions that there is no facility for doing this today.  I'll give option 2 a go initially.